# express route for a specific mac address

Tags: javascript, express, mac-address

I know is possible like [this](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-mac-address-filtering.html) but I ask anyway

considering a express route like:

```
 var express = require('express')
 var app = express()

app.get('/secure', function (req, res) {
 res.send('hello world')
})
```

is there any way to surround this route with an "if " or so that only allows this route to a specific mac address( computer mac adress)?

is there any possible way in express with node or javascript?

As someone answer, it says "only if the user send a mac address in their request" .... is it possible something like:

if ( contains a mac: address && is equal to "my mac number" ) ?

Comment: Not sure how you are going to get a mac address from an http request.

Comment: In my answer I say this is impossible. However, chances are there's an easier way to do whatever it is that you are trying to accomplish. What is your root goal? Why do you want to check the MAC address? I suggest posting another question containing the root problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. MAC addresses are not sent as part of an http request, so it is impossible to obtain one from a given request. The only way to get the client's MAC address is for the client to manually send it as a query string parameter.

Comment: ok, thanks, if this is the answer I would accept it soon in case someone comes with something else. Answering your question, I wonder if I can allow only my computer in a route on my website. Then just come to me if this is possible with the request, I have check if a request can contain mac address, haven't found anything so far. that was my main reason. If is possible to send mac address . please read something I add to my question above.